# Importing an excel file into SAS: named ranges longer than 32 characters

Tags: excel, import, sas, proc

I have an (2010) excel file with a long name for the sheet I want to import into SAS.  As a dummy example, suppose this sheet is called *somesheetnamethatislongenough* (this is 30 characters long - so is permissible as a sheet name in 2010 excel).  Now suppose I want to import just the range *C6:G200* in this sheet.  Now I should be able to do this by using the range= option in proc import as follows

```
proc import
    out=chk_xl_import
    datafile="somefilename.xlsx"
    replace
;
    range="somesheetnamethatislongenough$C6:G200";
    getnames=no;
run;
```

However, I get an error saying:

`ERROR 65-58: Name 'somesheetnamethatislongenough$C6:G200' is too long for a SAS name in this context.`

(Using the sheet=; option combined with range=; option gives the same error).  I thought I could work around this by using the excel engine in the libname statement, but I get the same problem.  So this code does not work either:

```
libname
    myxl_lib
    excel
    "somefilename.xlsx"
    header=NO
;

data chk_xl_lib;
    set myxl_lib."somesheetnamethatislongenough$C6:G200"n;
run;

libname myxl_lib clear;
```

I essentially get the same error:

`ERROR 307-185: The data set name cannot have more than 32 characters.`

Any thing that can be done, apart importing the whole sheet (i.e. delete the "C6:G200" from the range so that its less than 32 characters) and then sub-setting the resulting dataset in SAS?

Comment: As an aside, PROC IMPORT simply uses the LIBNAME engine on the back end, so that by itself won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to set up a named range in Excel, then refer to that in your import statement in SAS.  If you use the data step method then you don't need to put the range name as a name literal, e.g.

```
data chk_xl_lib;
set myxl_lib.named_range;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the excel file to get this to work, you can use [SQL Pass-Through Facility](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/syntaxidx/67925/HTML/default/index.htm#/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/67589/HTML/default/p0kmafpwgp04a2n11q7t5uc6rel0.htm).

```
proc sql;
  connect to excel (path="somefilename.xlsx");
  create table chk_xl_import as
  select * from connection to excel
    (
      select * from `somesheetnamethatislongenough$C6:G200`
    );
  disconnect from excel;
quit;
```

This might require that `SAS/Access Interface to PC Files` be installed for this to work.